# Backup Failed - Got Status Code 500

Tags: 12.04, backup

My automatic backup hasn't worked for a couple of days now. Everything was just peachy and I'm not sure what went wrong. The message just says:

Backup Failed
Got status code 500

No further information is given or offered. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a confirmed bug, you can watch it here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/882699

As of comment #16 there is only one workaround known: try to create another folder for your backup.